# Common Lisp - Consing Optimization question - loops and &rest parameters

Tags: optimization, common-lisp

I've finished an implementation of a language using Common Lisp, and I was seeking to optimize it as it takes ~1400s with Lisp instead of ~72 in Java. (Code here [cl-lox](https://github.com/AlbertoEAF/cl-lox)).

I launched the profiler and got this top culprits:

```
  seconds  |     gc     |     consed     |    calls    |  sec/call  |  name  
------------------------------------------------------------------
    32.879 |      0.000 |              0 | 104,512,464 |   0.000000 | LOX.INTERPRETER::LOOKUP-VARIABLE
     6.395 |      0.062 |  1,162,823,904 |  29,860,705 |   0.000000 | LOX.CALLABLE:LOX-CALLABLE-ARITY
     6.314 |      0.139 |  2,442,330,208 |  74,651,757 |   0.000000 | LOX.INTERPRETER::TYPE?
     5.220 |      0.000 |              0 |  59,721,406 |   0.000000 | LOX.INTERPRETER::CHECK-NUMBER-OPERANDS
     2.395 |      0.000 |              0 |  29,860,703 |   0.000000 | LOX.INTERPRETER::EVAL-TRUTHY-P
     0.062 |      0.000 |              0 |  29,860,703 |   0.000000 | LOX.INTERPRETER::TRUTHY-P
     0.001 |      0.000 |         65,520 |          35 |   0.000019 | LOX.RESOLVER:RESOLVE
```

Now here are some of the top culprits:

```
;;; Related to lox-callable-arity:

;; defclass++ is a macro on top of defclass to add accessors and a default constructor
(defclass++ lox-native-function (lox-callable)
  ((name :type string)
   (arity :type integer)
   (fn :type function)
   (str-repr :type string)))

(defmethod lox-callable-arity ((callee lox-native-function))
  (slot-value callee 'arity))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; Related to type? and check-number-operands

(defun type? (type-specifier &rest vars)
  "Ensure all vars are of type type-specifier."
  (loop for var in vars always (typep var type-specifier)))

(defun* check-number-operands ((operator token:token) left right)
  (when (not (type? 'number left right))
    (error 'lox.error:lox-runtime-error
           :token operator
           :message (format nil "Operands of '~A' must be numbers." @operator.lexeme))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Questions:

- What causes so much consing with lox-callable-arity?
- What causes so much consing with type?

  - Is it the loop?
  - Does the parameter `&rest args` cause consing - building the list args from `left right`?

    - I always pass only 2 parameters beside the type like in check-number-operands
    - Is there a performance advantage in defining a `type?` function that only takes `left right` instead of `&rest args` as argument?
  - I know I can replace `type?` with a macro but I'm baffled why one of the least complex operations in the program has so much weight.

Thank you :)

Comment: In `type?`, declaring `vars` to be `dynamic-extent` might solve its memory problems. Just put `(declare (dynamic-extent vars))` below the documentation string. This allows the compiler to stack allocate the variable and automatically free it when the function returns, without needing to involve the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from your profiler output that you are using SBCL.

The consing caused by `type?` is almost definitely a result of the `&rest` parameter. The loop should not cons enough to explain your profiling results, if at all. I ran some tests and found similar memory usage for `&rest` parameters containing two arguments. You can stack allocate the `vars` parameter as I mentioned in my comment or rewrite the function to take exactly three arguments as you mentioned.

The consing in `lox-callable-arity` is probably caused by the function making copies of the `arity` slot of the object when returning it (again my tests seem to support this theory). I think when you manually define a reader function it doesn't get some of the optimizations that SBCL applies to readers and accessors defined using `defclass` slot options, such as inlining. You should probably delete that definition and change your `arity` slot definition to `(arity :type integer :reader lox-callable-arity)` to more cleanly get an optimized reader function for the slot, or put `(declaim (inline lox-callable-arity))` above the method definition. My guess is that your `defclass++` macro uses `defmethod` to define the default accessors of the class. It should also be changed to use slot option accessors or inline functions to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks :) Actually defclass++ expands to a defclass with :accessor and :initarg and a metaclass that checks for types when setf'ing slots.